# Why does this function not return a value of 1 when I modify a character array in a separate else statement?

Tags: c, arduino

First, let me show you my code before I explain what is going on:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//Strings
char inData[20]; //Allocate some space for the string
char inChar; //Where to store the character read
byte index = 0; //Index into array; where to store the character

void setup()
{
  //Begin Serial Communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void){

  //Determine if command mode should be entered
  if(Comp("BTMODIFY") == 0)
  {
     Serial.print("Entering bluetooth command mode...); 
  }
}

char Comp(char* input){
  //Internal variables
  int i = 0;

  while(Serial.available() > 0) //Don't read unless you know there is data
  {
    if(index < 19) //One less than the size of the array
    {
      inChar = Serial.read(); //Read a character
      inData[index] = inChar; //Store it
      index++; //Increment where to write next
      inData[index] = '\0'; //Null terminate the string
    }
   }

  if(strcmp(inData, input) == 0){
    index = 0;
    inData[index] = '\0';
    return(0);
  }

  else{
    index = 0;
    inData[index] = '\0';
    return(1);
  }
}
```

This code is using parts of the Arduino library in addition to basic C code. The idea behind this code snippet is quite simple: if a user entered the string "BTMODIFY", print a statement to the terminal window. This event is detected by calling the function `Comp`.  This function copies whatever data is stored in the serial buffer to a character array.  Doing this allows me to compare the entered data to the target string, "BTMODIFY."

However, I'm encountering a problem. Note the last else block. If I comment these lines:

```
index = 0;
inData[index] = '\0';
```

then the code functions properly, meaning that when I type "BTMODIFY", a statement is printed on my terminal. As the code is now, nothing happens - which means that `if(Comp("BTMODIFY") == 0)` never evaluates to true. Obviously, there's something I'm missing.

The idea is to reuse the variable `inData`, so I'm simply placing a null terminator at the beginning of the character string.

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Comment: If you are entering BTMODIFY in a serial terminal it might be that you are actually inputting "BTMODIFY\n" to your program.

Comment: You are right. I'm sending both a clear and a new line signal along with the string, based upon my terminal settings. However, it hasn't seemed to pose a problem so far. The only issue is with the two lines in my else statement.

Comment: The fact that commenting out `index = 0; inData[index] = '\0'` makes me think that your function is reading serial data faster than it becomes available. Try changing to `while(Serial.available() > 8` or something like that. But then you might get the problem with the newline if you don't read in fast enough.

Comment: Interesting idea. I've removed the new line escape, (residual of using AT-commands for an HC-05 bluetooth chip), and will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

The program is probably stuck in an infinite loop:

```
  while(Serial.available() > 0) //Don't read unless you know there is data
  {
    if(index < 19) //One less than the size of the array
    {
      inChar = Serial.read(); //Read a character
      ...
    }
  }
```

Consider the case, when `Serial.available() > 0`, and `index >= 19`. The data is not being read, and the `while` loop goes on.

Try adding `else break;`:

```
  int truncated = 0;
  while(Serial.available() > 0) //Don't read unless you know there is data
  {
    if(index < 19) //One less than the size of the array
    {
      inChar = Serial.read(); //Read a character
      inData[index] = inChar; //Store it
      index++; //Increment where to write next
      inData[index] = '\0'; //Null terminate the string
    }
    else
    {
      truncated = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  if(truncated && strncmp(inData, input, 19) == 0){
    index = 0;
    inData[index] = '\0';
    return(0);
  }
  else if(!truncated && strcmp(inData, input) == 0) {
    ...
  }
  else {
    ...
  }
```

Or, you could rewrite the Comp function:

```
int Comp(char* input) {
  //Internal variables
  int i = 0;

  int curr = 0;
  while(Serial.available() > 0) //Don't read unless you know there is data
  {
    if(index < 19) //One less than the size of the array
    {
      inChar = Serial.read(); //Read a character
      if(input[curr] == '\0') return 0; // Input ended, but data is still there.
      if(input[curr++] != inChar) return 0; // Data doesn't match.
    }
    else return 1;  // Data matches.
   }

   return 1;  // Data matches.
}
```

Comment: Nice hypothesis. (+1)

Comment: I agree, it's interesting. It would seem to create an infinite loop since the data is being pushed out of the buffer when `Serial.read()` isn't being called. However, it did not work.

Comment: Then the following `if` statement: `(strcmp(inData, input) == 0)` wouldn't be true, if the data was truncated. Use `strncmp` instead.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but the solution doesn't seem to fit the symptoms I'm experiencing. If I comment the two statements before `return(1)` in my original else block, the code behaves as I expect (a statement prints out - no infinite loop). However, as soon as I add those two lines back in, it stops functioning (nothing prints out).

Comment: I can't solve your problem. However you can try changing the `Comp` function, to see if it works. (Just remove the whole goddamned bug!)

Comment: Also, I am assuming you have proper quotes in this line:
`Serial.print("Entering bluetooth command mode...");`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm probably going to rewrite the whole function and reevaluate the logic of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it could have to do with the speed of reading vs the speed of executing your function. Below is a totally untested and uncompiled code that I think (hope) will do what you want.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define MAXLEN 20

char getline(char* unsigned int);

void setup()
{
  //Begin Serial Communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void){

  //Determine if command mode should be entered
  char cmd[MAXLEN];
  while (!getline(cmd, MAXLEN))
      ; // Wait for a complete input line

  if(strcmp("BTMODIFY", cmd) == 0)
  {
     Serial.print("Entering bluetooth command mode..."); 
  }
}

char getline(char* input, unsigned int size){
  static unsigned int i = 0;
  static char done = 0;

  while(Serial.available() > 0
          && i < size-1
          && !done)
  {
    char c = Serial.read(); //Read a character
    input[i++] = c;         //Store it and increment
    if (c == '\n')          //Or whatever newline your serial terminal is sending
    {
        done = 1;
    }
  }
  input[i] = '\0';

  if (done)
  {
    done = 0;
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Comp()` is called many times *as* data is arriving.

`Serial.available()` returns 0 most of the time and then with `else` block in place, the count of `char` in `inData`  is set to 0.

If `Serial.available()` does return 1, that single `char` is put in `inData`.  The next call to `Serial.available()` could easily return 0 as this code is far faster than data arriving.  With the `else` block in place, the count is zero-ed again.

Without the `else` block, data has a chance to 1) accumulate in `inData` and match `"BTMODIFY"` or 2) fill the buffer and no more matches.

The key logic mistake is assuming that data arrives on the serial interface all at once  instead of having potential large gaps of time (from the CPU's point of view) between `char`.

Suggested changes:
1) When the buffer is full, empty the eldest `char`. Treat `inData` as a FIFO.
2) Test for a match after each `char`.
3) Avoid magic numbers like 19 - used derived values.

```
char Comp(const char* input) {
  size_t len = strlen(input);
  int i = 0;
  while(Serial.available() > 0) {
    if (index > (sizeof inData - 2)) {
      // toss eldest `char`
      index = sizeof inData - 2;
      memmove(&inData[0], &inData[1], index);
    }
    inChar = Serial.read(); //Read a character
    inData[index] = inChar; //Store it
    index++; //Increment where to write next
    inData[index] = '\0'; //Null terminate the string  **

    if(index >= len && memcmp(&inData[index-len], input, len) == 0) {
      index = 0;
      inData[index] = '\0'; // **
      return(0);
    }
  }
  return(1);
}
```

** These steps not needed and `inData` could be size 19